# Accepting variables in sage BooleanPolynomialRing

Tags: python, sage

I am trying to write a sage function.

In the following, code block B uses variables such as x0,x1,x2,x3. Im trying to generalize code block B as code block A. res[1] in code block A is a list which contains the four variables. However, on executing, I get the following error:

```
**ValueError: variable names must be alphanumeric, but one is 'res[_sage_const_1 ]' which is not.**
```

Is there any way I can make the code block accept the list elements?

**Note: degreeAndMonomialsCalculate() is just a function which returns degree of a function in res[0] and its unique monomials(variables) in res[1]**

**Code Block A**

```
def annihilatorReturn(function):
    res=degreeAndMonomialsCalculate(function)
    A.<res[1]>=BooleanPolynomialRing(len(res[1]))
    X=BooleanFunction(function)
    B=X.annihilator(res[0])
    return B
```

**Code Block B**

```
def annihilatorReturn():
    A.<x0,x1,x2,x3>=BooleanPolynomialRing(4)
    Y=x0*x1*x2+x2*x1+x2*x3+x3*x1
    X=BooleanFunction(Y)
    B=X.annihilator(3)
    return B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it's typical to have a "minimal working example", so that we don't need your extra functions.

There are two problems here.  First, even if the error you got was avoided, you'd get this one.

```
def test():
    res = ['x1','x2']
    A.<res> = BooleanPolynomialRing(len(res))
    return A
....: 
sage: test()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<snip>
IndexError: the number of names must equal the number of generators
```

This is because Sage *preparses* the invalid Python `A.<res> ...` into something else that is valid.

```
sage: preparse("A.<res> = BooleanPolynomialRing(len(res))")
"A = BooleanPolynomialRing(len(res), names=('res',)); (res,) = A._first_ngens(1)"
```

This also causes your issue:

```
sage: res = ['x','y']
sage: A.<res> = BooleanPolynomialRing(len(res))
<snip>
ValueError: variable names must be alphanumeric, but one is 'res[Integer(1)]' which is not.
```

and I don't see an easy way around it with this syntax.  However,

```
sage: res = [2,['x','y']]
sage: A = BooleanPolynomialRing(names=res[1])
sage: A
Boolean PolynomialRing in x, y
```

seems like it should do the job.  See

```
sage: BooleanPolynomialRing?
```

for more info.